# AngularJS API for local database, Where to start?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, xampp, mariadb

Im new to relatively new web development on a professional side. I got about 30 tabs open and looking for a good starting point

I got an angularJS project and i got the code working for what i needs to do. I need to modify it to use a local database (which eventually will be on a server). 
Now instead of using a json object I need to pull and push some data from and to a database. I was recommended Node.js  for this.

But I honestly have no clue where to start and **desperately** need a good starting point with manipulating my mySQL(mariadb if that matters) db from the Angularjs side.

My understanding is AngularJS > Server script(Node.js) > Database

Using xampp for my apache and mysql.

I have beginner experience with vanilla javascript and web developing in general.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: why not **AngularJS > PHP > MySQL**. E.g. `$http.post("file.php", json).then(...)` > `$json= json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` ... (`mysqli::query`) `"INSERT INTO ... VALUES(...)"`

Comment: Why not node.js? I never used php or nodejs

Comment: Node.js works best with REST API. But if you have MySQL, then it's easier with PHP support

Comment: I'd prefer to use something like node since Im more familiar with it. After a few hours of looking through things. Im wondering if I should do the server side of things like query calls before I do other stuff like front end stuff with AngularJS. Any feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for my **own project**, starting somewhere good was both a little of front-end and back-end. I needed the basic front-end to test and debug the server side script that processes my data.

My process so far has been build the database then write the code for the API (I'm using node.js). I then wrote the front end that let me send data. Now that the important part of the project which is saving user info is done, smaller functionality over the site is to be built.

Hope this helps anyone new starting maybe to give them an idea where to start.